# Adding admin through MYSQL is not working

Tags: wordpress

I am using a WordPress site. By mistake I deleted my wp_usermeta in MySQL (PHPMYADMIN) After that I am not able to access the admin dashboard of my site.

I am able to log in as a user but not able to access my profile page.

Comment: You don't have a backup of your DB?

Comment: No sir I don't have